# Focusrite Saffire Pro - signal but no sound

Tags: sound, firewire

I am utilizing Ubuntu 12.04 with the KXDE desktop environment. JACK (qjackctl), ffado-mixer, and the the Focusrite Saffire Pro 40 itself appears to be receiving signal (to include LED meter input). However, I have no audible sound output from front headphone connections or individual outs (i.e. direct input or media play). I have uninstalled Pulse Audio to ensure that there is no conflict. Seems like this should be a minor oversight on my part. Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get no output from the port on the device itself, but it's getting input, it sounds like a hardware problem with the device, or you need to turn some other knobs, or push a button, to enable the headphones or adjust their volume, and the issue is totally unrelated to Ubuntu.

Comment: Initially, I thought that would be the obvious reason. However, the device works flawlessly on my MacBook Pro with all the DAW's that I utilize. As I stated in my previous post, it's probably a minor oversight on my part that hopefully will be resolved with ongoing troubleshooting. Nonetheless, thanks for your response.

kj

Comment: When you say "the KXDE desktop environment" do you mean *LXDE* (or *Xfce* or *KDE*)?

Comment: Please forgive me, indeed I meant LXPanel 0.5.8 desktop environment. I've tried various firewire related settings in JACK to no avail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I'm going to answer it anyway, as I am the only person I've seen actually fix this issue, and this comes up on google search results.

So, I have the Saffire Pro 40 as well. The audio won't kick in unless I restart my computer. If this sounds like your problem here's how to fix it:

1. open Saffire MixControl
2. click Settings in the bottom right(ish)
3. click Active Monitor Pad
4. Click settings again and turn off Active Monitor Pad

For some reason, this works. I can't explain it, but it does the trick for me.